# Self hosting with IIS windows 10 (Had it working No clue what step I am missing)

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, web-hosting

Been stuck on this for hours I have a domain that I have properly updated DNS records to point to my IP. I have an MVC5 site I have built as a display for a Halloween game coming up. I had guests register online and the domain working on IIS ad www.mydomain.com/register.

I switched my project back to IIS Express and removed the site from IIS. I cannot for the life of me get IIS to show anything but the default blue IIS page (I can even access it remotely, firewall and router exceptions on the port remain) and I am pulling my hair out. I feel like I need to convert my site to an application, but only see that option if I create a virtual folder which in turns screws up my URL (the invites with the old URL have already went out) Any advice on what I might be missing or would be great.

Happy to provide more info if needed as well if this was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had my router forwarding the specified port to port 80. I was configuring IIS to the external port.